# Random URL in Swift 5 / Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to play a random radio station using the following struct:

```
struct RadioStreamer {
    
    let streamingURL: URL
    
    var  radios = ["https://a", "https://b.mp3", "https://c.mp3", "d.mp3", "e.mp3"]
    
    
    private let player: AVPlayer?
    private let playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    
    
    init() {
        self.streamingURL =  URL (string:radios.randomElement()!)!
        print(radios.randomElement() as Any)
        
        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: self.streamingURL)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
        
    }
    
    public func playStreaming() { self.player?.play() }
    public func pauseStreaming() { self.player?.pause() }
}
```

and then in SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var streamer = RadioStreamer()
    
    
    Button(action: {
        
        self.streamer.pauseStreaming()
        
        self.streamer.playStreaming()
        
        
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "forward.end").resizable()
        .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .foregroundColor(.buttonColor)
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when the button forward is clicked a new url will be loaded.
I assume the problem is that the random is computed when I  initialise  var streamer = RadioStreamer() so the question is..how can I randomise it by calling again RadioStreamer when the forward button is pressed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to solve this problem. Option 1 is keep the same RadioStreamer that you have, and just recreate it every time you need a new player. You'd have to make it a `@State` variable to do it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var streamer = RadioStreamer()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
            self.streamer.pauseStreaming()
            
            self.streamer = RadioStreamer()
            
            self.streamer.playStreaming()
            
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "forward.end").resizable()
            .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .foregroundColor(.buttonColor)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
}
```

That way, the old streamer gets paused (if it's playing), a new one gets created, thus triggering your `init` method which chooses a random element, and then gets started.

The second is to make `RadioStreamer` a class and modify it so that it can change its `player` and `playerItem` properties. *Note that it's now a class, not a struct, so that it can modify its own properties without using `inout`*

```
class RadioStreamer {
    
    var streamingURL: URL?
    
    var  radios = ["https://a", "https://b.mp3", "https://c.mp3", "d.mp3", "e.mp3"]
    
    private var player: AVPlayer?
    private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    
    public func createRandomPlayer() {
        guard let streamingURL = URL (string:radios.randomElement()!) else {
            assertionFailure("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        print(streamingURL)
        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: streamingURL)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
        self.streamingURL = streamingURL
    }
    
    public func playStreaming() { self.player?.play() }
    public func pauseStreaming() { self.player?.pause() }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var streamer = RadioStreamer()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
                self.streamer.pauseStreaming()
            
                self.streamer.createRandomPlayer()
               
                self.streamer.playStreaming()
            
            
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "forward.end").resizable()
            .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
    
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer the second route, with another addition -- I'd make `RadioStreamer` an `ObservableObject` and put some @Published properties on it like `isPlaying` that I could reflect in my view.

Comment: amazing! first solution is perfect for my needs because if paused the URL remains the same but if next then a new URL is generated. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score -1):

In your `RadioStreamer` class, change `player` and `playerItem` to `var`s.

Add a function `makeRandomPlayer()` that picks a random URL string and uses it to populate the `player` and `playerItem`.

Call `self.streamer.makeRandomPlayer()` from your button action.

Comment: can you please provide a code sample ? I tried but I get some errors (e.g. cannot assign property to self in the makeRandomPlayer function).

Comment: So add your attempted code at the end of your question along with the errors you're getting.